# Highlight variables with type `any` in a typescript source file?

Tags: neovim

I use neovim (0.8) with built-in LSP, and I program in typescript

I would like to highlight variables that have type `any` in a clearly visible color (maybe even background color instead of just foreground). Instances of type `any` can be intentional or unintentional, but either way, it is often concerning, so it is good to at least know and highlighting type `any` with syntax highlighting would be useful

Are there any ideas for how this could be done?

Answer (score 1):

Normally I'd modify the syntax rules a bit, but looking at the syntax file in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/shared/typescriptcommon.vim` it seems this would require overriding/duplicating quite a lot of stuff in your local vimrc, which isn't easy and may break on future updates. The easier option here would probably to use `matchadd()`.

First define a highlight group to use with the colours you'd like to use:

```
:hi typescriptAny guibg=#ff9999 guifg=#000000
```

Using `guifg` and `guibg` assumes that you're using "true colours" ('termguicolors' is enabled); you can use ctermfg and ctermbg if it's not. See `:help highlight` for more information.

Then define a match:

```
:call matchadd('typescriptAny', ': *\zsany')
```

This will highlight `any` in function signatures: a `:` followed by zero or more spaces, and then `any`. The `\zs` in there sets the start of the match, to prevent `:`  getting highlighted. I'm not super-familiar with TypeScript syntax, but I believe this should highlight `any` in most (or all?) of the relevant places. There's a caveat though:

```
// the downside is: any also gets highlighted here.
// function x(foo: any, arg: number) {
console.log("OK: any values satisfies check")
```

The match is "dumb" and will apply to any text, including comments.

I did a bit of grepping on my ~/code and ~/src and found 105 instances in total where it would apply wrongly, on 6.4 million lines of code, or about once every 61k lines of code. Personally, I think that's acceptable.

You can maybe restrict the pattern a bit more too; maybe something like:

```
: *\zsany\ze\%( *[\[,){=]\|$\)
```

That will match `any` only if it's followed by any of `[,){=` or if it's at the end of the line. I'm not familiar enough with TypeScript to know if that's good enough, but it seems alright if I open a few TypeScript files.

---

To load this automatically for TypeScript files you can load it with an autocmd:

```
augroup myts
    au!
    au filetype typescript 
                \  hi typescriptAny guibg=#ff9999 guifg=#000000
                \| call matchadd('typescriptAny', ': *\zsany')
augroup end
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I think what I am looking for may involve actually getting the data about the variable type from LSP though. I know that I can get the variable type from e.g. vim.lsp.buf.hover. I have also seen recently that using inlay hints could be a way to do it, but they are a bit visually noisy

Answer (score 0):

I found one possible way to help with this issue that incorporates ESlint, LSP, and typescript typechecking. The eslint rules go BEYOND what typescript provides with just noImplicitAny and stuff like this.

a) turn on the ESLint set of rules @typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking  on your project

b) turn on LSP integration for eslint, so that it will highlight lines with errors or warnings

I had not even realized that @typescript-eslint had this special set of rules related to type-checking

See set of rules enabled by this here

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/src/configs/recommended-requiring-type-checking.ts

the set of rules called 'unsafe' will warn about use of "`any`" types e.g. these ones

```
'@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument': 'error',
'@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment': 'error',
'@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call': 'error',
'@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access': 'error',
'@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return': 'error',
```